# How to retain CAD symbology and text in GIS format

Tags: cad

I have a DXF/DWG files from AutoCAD and I'd like to retain the symbology and text when I import this file into QGIS.

I don't have access to FME or AutoCAD so I'd like to know if there is a way to do this using open source tools. Alternatively, if there is a safe file that you can download to import the symbology and text into QGIS or even PostGIS. Is that possible?

When I open the attribute table in QGIS I have something like this in the 'text' field
`\pxqc;\f@Arial Unicode MS|b0|i0|c0|p34;8am-5pm`

Comment: Can you try ArcGIS for read CAD files?

Comment: I wish but I don't have ArcGIS either. Thanks @KinanAlQassem